# Unable to update the table of SQL Server with BCP utility

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, windows-vista, bcp

We have a database table that we pre-populate with data as part of our deployment procedure.  Since one of the columns is binary (it's a binary serialized object) we use `BCP` to copy the data into the table.

So far this has worked very well, however, today we tried this technique on a `Windows Server 2008` machine for the first time and noticed that not all of the columns were being updated.  Out of the `31 rows` that are normally inserted as part of this operation, only `2 rows` actually had their `binary columns` populated correctly.  The other 29 rows simply had null values for their `binary column`.  This is the first situation where we've seen an issue like this and this is the same .dat file that we use for all of our deployments.

Has anyone else ever encountered this issue before or have any insight as to what the issue could be?

Thanks in advance,
Jeremy

Comment: SQL Server I assume... 2005 or 2008?

Comment: Yes, sorry SQL Server 2005.  We've actually run this on Developer and Enterprise Edition so far without issue.  The machine we're seeing issue on is actually running Standard Edition.  I'm not sure if that's contributing to the issue or not.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're using -c or -w to dump as text, and it's choking on a particular combination of characters it doesn't like and subbing in a NULL. This can also happen in Native mode if there's no format file. Try the following and see if it helps. (Obviously, you'll need to add the server and login switches yourself.)

```
bcp MyDatabase.dbo.MyTable format nul -f MyTable.fmt -n
bcp MyDatabase.dbo.MyTable out MyTable.dat -f MyTable.fmt -k -E -b 1000 -h "TABLOCK"
```

This'll dump the table data as straight binary with a format file, NULLs, and identity values to make *absolutely* sure everything lines up. In addition, it'll use batches of 1000 to optimize the data dump. Then, to insert it back:

```
bcp MySecondData.dbo.MyTable in MyTable.dat -f MyTable.fmt -n -b 1000
```

...which will use the format file, data file, and set batching to increase the speed a little. If you need more speed than that, you'll want to look at BULK INSERT, FirstRow/LastRow, and loading in parallel, but that's a bit beyond the scope of this question. :)